# Displaying wide chars with printf

Tags: c, encoding, printf, widechar

I'm trying to understand how does printf work with wide characters (`wchar_t`).

I've made the following code samples :

## Sample 1 :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main(void)
{
    wchar_t     *s;

    s = (wchar_t *)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 2);
    s[0] = 42;
    s[1] = 0;
    printf("%ls\n", s);
    free(s);
    return (0);
}
```

**output :**

```
*
```

Everything is fine here : my character (`*`) is correctly  displayed.

## Sample 2 :

I wanted to display an other kind of character. On my system, `wchar_t` seem encoded  on 4 bytes. So I tried to display the following character :
[`É`](http://unicode-table.com/en/00C9/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main(void)
{
    wchar_t     *s;

    s = (wchar_t *)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 2);
    s[0] = 0xC389;
    s[1] = 0;
    printf("%ls\n", s);
    free(s);
    return (0);
}
```

But there is no output this time, I tried with many values from the "encoding" section (cf. previous link) for `s[0]` (0xC389, 201, 0xC9)... But I never get the `É` character displayed. I also tried with `%S` instead of `%ls`.

If I try to call printf like this : `printf("<%ls>\n", s)` the only character printed is `'<'`, the display is truncated.

Why do I have this problem? How should I do?

Comment: Is there a reason you allocate dynamically instead of declaring an array of two elements?

Comment: Try reading with `scanf("%1ls")` a `"É"` and report what value for `printf("%lX\n", (unsigned long) s[0])` you get.

Comment: @chux `printf("%ld\n", (unsigned long int) L'É');` gives me `201`.

Comment: Suggest report the result of  "reading with `scanf("%1ls")` an "É".  Your comment reports what the source code thinks a 'É' is.  We are interested in how the code handles the I/O, which may differ in character encoding.

Comment: On my system, the return value from  `scanf("%1ls", s);` is -1  (`s[0]` not set), which supports http://stackoverflow.com/a/40600658/2410359

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Why do I have this problem?

Make sure you check `errno` and the return value of `printf`!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{
    wchar_t *s;
    s = (wchar_t *) malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 2);
    s[0] = 0xC389;
    s[1] = 0;

    if (printf("%ls\n", s) < 0) {
        perror("printf");
    }

    free(s);
    return (0);
}
```

See the output:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
printf: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

## How to fix

First of all, the default locale of a C program is `C` (also known as `POSIX`) which is ASCII-only. You will need to add a call to `setlocale`, specifically `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")`.

If your `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE` or `LANG` environment variables are not set to allow UTF-8 when blank, you'll have to explicitly select a locale. `setlocale(LC_ALL, "C.UTF-8")` works on most systems - `C` is standard, and the `UTF-8` subset of `C` is generally implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{
    wchar_t *s;
    s = (wchar_t *) malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 2);
    s[0] = 0xC389;
    s[1] = 0;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    if (printf("%ls\n", s) < 0) {
        perror("printf");
    }

    free(s);
    return (0);
}
```

See the output:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
쎉
```

The reason why the incorrect character printed out is because `wchar_t` represents a wide character (such as UTF-32), not a multibyte character (such as UTF-8). Note that `wchar_t` is always 32 bits wide in the GNU C Library, but the C standard doesn't require it to be. If you initialize the character using the `UTF-32BE` encoding (i.e. `0x000000C9`), then it prints out correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{
    wchar_t *s;
    s = (wchar_t *) malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 2);
    s[0] = 0xC9;
    s[1] = 0;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    if (printf("%ls\n", s) < 0) {
        perror("printf");
    }

    free(s);
    return (0);
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
É
```

Note that you can also set the `LC` (locale) environment variables via command line:

```
$ LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
$ ./a.out
É
```

Answer (score 5):

One problem is that you are trying to encode UTF-8, which is a single-byte encoding scheme, as a multi-byte encoding. For UTF-8 you use plain `char`.

Also note that because you try to combine the UTF-8 sequence into a multi-byte type, you have [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (byte-order) issues (in memory `0xC389` might be stored as `0x89` and `0xC3`, in that order). *And* that the compiler will sign-extend your number as well (if `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4` and you look at `s[0]` in a debugger it might be `0xFFFFC389`).

Another problem is the terminal or console you use to print. Maybe it simply doesn't support UTF-8 or the other encodings you tried?

Answer (score 5):

I found a simple way to print wide chars. One key point is `setlocale()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    // setlocale(LC_ALL, "C.UTF-8"); // this also works

    wchar_t hello_eng[] = L"Hello World!";
    wchar_t hello_china[] = L"世界, 你好!";
    wchar_t *hello_japan = L"こんにちは日本!";
    printf("%ls\n", hello_eng);
    printf("%ls\n", hello_china);
    printf("%ls\n", hello_japan);

    return 0;
}
```