# Visual studios changes my '£' to '?' during runtime

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ascii

For some reason VS swaps "£" for "?"

For instance:
cout << "Price: £" << price << endl;

outputs:

Price: ?xx.xx

Doesn't matter where I place a "£", it always outputs a "?"

Anybody got any idea what this is?!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831289/inserting-a-%C2%A3-sign-in-an-output-string-in-c

Comment: the character encoding of your source file probably doesn't match the character set of your console. Please show a [mre]

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't do anything like that. `?` will only appear if a file is saved as ASCII using the wrong codepage. This can happen with *any* application and is essentially a coding bug.. I wonder what codepage was used as `£` appears in almost all codepages.

Comment: In any case, post your code. Almost certainly, you aren't using Unicode strings (ie u16string/char16_t or wstring/wchar in older versions of the language). Windows strings are UTF16 and applications are expected to use Unicode since the late 1990s

Comment: Works on my machine.  I'm using UTF-16 output, from UTF-8 strings.  Is that what you are using?